# Directing Domain Name to Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis, domain-name

I am developing web pages and deployed it in Tomcat. I want it to share among my friends. I read about IIS and Apache.Please suggest me any way to direct domain name to tomcat installed in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would stay away from IIS.

Deploy an instance of Apache/HTTPD in windows - and proxy/reverse-proxy the traffic on whatever port you want to your tomcat instance.

You can find some decent resources as for Windows deployables here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html

Then when you have your server set up and functioning, look into the `ProxyPass` directive within Apache.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Don't forget to open a port forwarding on your router, if necessary.

As far as directing your domain name to your computer, look into getting an account at [ZoneEdit](http://www.zoneedit.com) to set up your DNS to point whatever domain name you want to your routers/cable modems IP address. Then you can set up your port forwarding.